# Clarifications about units of Photon Flux (PF) and Photon Flux Density (PFD)

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, light-emitting-diodes

I have an emitting source of light ([this](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-8405100/GD%20QSSPA1.14_EN.pdf) LED - Light Emitting Diode, `UO` variant).
On page 5 I read the minimum `PF` Photon Flux is 2.49 umol/s.

That means **every second 2.49 umol of photons are emitted**, in any direction.

Now, let's put an ideal lens in front of the LED. This ideal lens has no losses and can focus all the photons in an area of, say, 0.01 m² at 1 m of distance.

Under such hypotheses, do you agree that the total amount of photons that reach the target are still 2.49 umol/s? (in a real world scenario, they are surely lower due to losses and imperfection of the lens)

What about the `PFD` Photon Flux Density? Doing the math it would result:

```
PFD = PF / surface = 249 umol/s/m²
```

As the initial quantity of photons is 2.49 umol/s, they cannot be more than this value. So the `PFD` value is just saying that *theoretically* there are 249 umol/s on 1 m², but in reality this density is present only inside the target (0.01 m²) and 0 elsewhere.

My questions is: **if I put an object in the target spot, how many photons it will actually receive?**

I explain a bit further the origin of the question. This LEDs are for horticulture, hence in the target there will be a plant. Let's say I have the requirement to provide 200 umol/s to this plant (that cover the entire target surface). Is this requirement fulfilled in this scenario? The math seems to be ok, but my common sense says: **"no, because no matter how well you can focus your photons, they still are 2.49 umol/s!"**

Comment: That is why you put 100 of these diodes on a mount. 100 of these diodes will use 100W and you will have a total of 250µmol/s available.

Comment: @JoséAndrade, ok but can you provide a simple demonstration to fully understand why the common sense is right and not my math?

Comment: Your math is correct. But like you said, only a 0.01m² area of the plant is being given the 249µmol/s

Comment: @JoséAndrade that's what I don't understand! It makes sense if the source provides 2.49 umol/s/m², but since the source provides 2.49 umol/s even focusing it on 0.01 m² I should have 2.49 umol/s in that small area, not more. Otherwise I can fullfill the requirements with only 1 LED

Comment: I should have been more careful with the units and should have added the area on my previous post, because, as I wrote it, its misleading. On that area only 2.49µmol are falling per second. However you calculated the PFD but you want to know the PF requirement. They are not the same number. If the plant needs 200 µmol/s, then the whole plant should get that. PFD is important in order to not burn the plant. You could give 200µmol/s but if the area is just 0.01m², then you will burn the plant.

Comment: @JoséAndrade let's see if I understood. Given the above setup, on my target area I will have a PF of 2.49 umol/s (100% of emitted photons) while the PFD is actually unknown since we don't know the source PFD?

Comment: Or the PDF is 249 umol/s/m², but it doesn't matter as the requirement at the target is PF, not PFD!

Comment: The PFD is definitely 249µmol/(sm²). If the rest of the missing area (0.99m²) had the same type of illumination as on that 0.01m², then that whole area (1m²) was getting 249µmol/s